# Write something below ampersand sign

Tags: math-operators

I need to write something below and top of ampersand sign. I want it to be like `\sum`. I have tried

```
\&_{i = 0}^{n}
```

but it shows  `i=0` in the index but not below ampersand sign.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\amper}{\&}

\begin{document}
Inline: $\amper_{i=1}^n$

Inline with display: $\amper\limits_{i=1}^n$

Display: \[ \amper_{i=1}^n \] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted the ampersand to display larger in display style, you can use `scalerel` package to grow the size to match the vertical extent of the `\sum` sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\scalerel*{\&}{\sum}}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\[ \foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \]
\centering This is inline: \(\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)
\end{document}
```

[image]